# can't Get stream of mp3 file in wp7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, nullreferenceexception

i'm building a wp7 application for a game using silverlight & XNA 
 i have an mp3 file called  "`Punch1.mp3`" `(Build action : resource )`  stored inside a folder called "`SoundEffects"` inside the project folder

and i want to play the file using this code

```
         StreamResourceInfo info;

         Uri myuri = new Uri("/SoundEffects/Punch1.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
         info = App.GetResourceStream (myuri);
         punch1 = SoundEffect.FromStream(info.Stream ) ;
```

punch is defined in the code here :

```
public static SoundEffect punch1;
```

the problem is that it raises a nullreference exception in the third line claiming that info is null 
and that's true in the debugging mode , i found that the resource stream info is null
i think this is because the it can't read the file although the uri is correct

[image]

Comment: can you please paste code that refers to what info an punch1 are need to see where you declare these please.. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the following code :

```
     Uri myuri = new Uri("/SoundEffects/Punch1.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
     info = App.GetResourceStream (myuri);
     punch1 = SoundEffect.FromStream(info.Stream ) ;
```

`SoundEffect.FromStream()` expects a wave file stream not an MP3 as shown here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx .
so solution to find a mp3 > wav convertor or just find another way to load mp3 to WP7

considering the picture this is normal URI in normal cases can't evaluate expression of isfile .

Answer (score 2):

You can try two things

```
- Clean and rebuild the project
- Try appending project name in URI "/PhoneApp1;component/SoundEffects/Punch.mp3"
```

Comment: when i append the project name this would be an absolute or relative uri ?

Comment: I think it would be relative because you are still accessing it relatively through your project

Comment: i've tried and didn't work , also i've tried on another pc didn't work as well

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the XNA assembly anyway, you can use [TitleContainer.OpenStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.titlecontainer.openstream.aspx) instead (with a relative URI) and have the audio file build set as `Content`.

Comment: i've tried the code above here : 
             Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(@"soundeffects\ahhh1.mp3");
             punch1 = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream) ; 
the stream object managed to read the file and when debugging it has a lenght and offset which seems promising 
but the second line rises a InvalidOperationException

Comment: That exception is being thrown because `FromStream` expects a wave file, not an MP3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx You'll have to convert it if you want to use the `FromStream` method. But you can still use the `TitleContainer.OpenStream` method to load the WAV.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Haris Haqsan that your URI string is bad.

```
Uri myuri = new Uri("/PhoneBoxing;component/SoundEffects/Punch1.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
```

But you should also consider switching to using content files instead embedding them at resources as it can help your application start up time.  Depending on the amount of files we are talking about, it can make a big difference.

Set your Build Action to content and your code should look like:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("/SoundEffects/Punch1.mp3", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: the uri is working well the problem was fromstream method accepts only wav files

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue on my machine, the InvalidOperationException is a little confusing.  All I had to do was re-encode the wav file to the specifications [listed on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx).

After I did that, it worked perfectly.